# How to implement x-frame in Backbase

Tags: x-frame-options, backbase

How to implement x-frame in Backbase. Anyone can explain about it and how to implement it. Any help would appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not something that you can configure in the Backbase product.

[Backbase advises](https://my.backbase.com/qa/topic/details//1310) that you **configure your webserver** to always serve `X-Frame-Option = SAMEORIGIN` for all pages served.